# AWS GLUE: MySQL through SSH Tunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, aws-glue-connection

I need to connect to an on-prem database that I normally access from within the enterprise VPN, and then through an SSH tunnel. We already have a VPC on AWS configured for our own VPN, but I could not figure out how to create a Glue Connection with SSH tunneling.

I can therefore create Glue connections for databases I can access just by connecting to the company VPN, but not for those that need SSH.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer this, but provides some context for anyone going to answer: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-to-access-and-analyze-on-premises-data-stores-using-aws-glue/

Comment: Tunnel means using a separate component that has connections to both the client and to the database, right? You can open the tunnel separately, and configure Glue to connect to this tunnel. Glue does not have to be aware that it is a tunneling connection.